# Find the number of distinct real roots of a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, proof-explanation, roots

Suppose we have the polynomial

$f(x) = a x^4 + bx^3 + cx^2+dx+e $

where a-e are real.

Can someone please help explain why the following is definitely not true:

$f(x)= 1$ has 1 distinct real solution

$f(x)= 2$ has 3 distinct real solutions

$f(x)= 3$ has 2 distinct real solutions

and $f(x)= 4$ has 4 distinct real solutions

yet the following could be true

$f(x)= 1$ has 1 distinct real solution

$f(x)= 2$ has 2 distinct real solutions

$f(x)= 3$ has 4 distinct real solutions

and $f(x)= 4$ has 3 distinct real solutions

I thought that by the fundamental theorem of algebra that f(x) has 4 roots.  Therefore $f(x) - \alpha$ for some constant $\alpha$ should have four roots.  And because complex roots come in pairs how could for example $f(x)= 4$ have 3 distinct real solutions?

Comment: FTA gives you the number of *complex* roots. Here, you ask about *real* roots. Do you want a polynomial that verifies ALL the conditions, or one at a time ?

Comment: How many distinct real roots does $x^2(x-1)(x-2)=0$ have?

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS I'm looking for the reason why a single polynomial cannot satisfy the first set of conditions but could the second

Comment: @MarkBennet that makes sense, thanks.  How would you tackle the problem, any tips on how to get started?

Comment: For example: $\;f(x)=x^4+2\;$ shows that 1-2 could be false (meaning: not necessarily true *always*, which I believe is what you mean) . Also, $\;f(x)=x^4+4\;$ shows the last one could be false. The difference between both sets of questions: "definitely not true" (??), and "could be true" seems to be pretty foggy...

Comment: @DonAntonio the question states that there is no polynomial satisfies the first set on conditions, but you could find a polynomial which satisfies the second set.

Comment: I think the best way is to draw a picture. An odd number of roots (for $P(x)-\alpha$) means there is a multiple root, hence an horizontal tangent. I'll give you an example that satisfies the second set of solutions, you'll see what I mean. Anyway, this is a real analysis problem, not an algebra problem.

Comment: By the conjugate root theorem, complex roots come in pairs. That is if $a + bi$ is a root of $f(x)$ then so too is $a - bi$. So for a polynomial with real coefficients, its impossible to have an odd number of complex roots (well, at least complex roots that are not real).

Comment: @darren86 And then why in the world didn't you write **exactly** that?!

Comment: @mfl No, we don't.  Try $x^4 - x^2$.

Comment: I would try to draw a sketch of the possible shapes of a quartic curve (a $W$ or upside-down $W$, or with merged - or missing - turning points) and look at the possible ways a bunch of horizontal lines can cross it. Then use continuity arguments to exclude what is evidently impossible - note there is a turning point between each pair of zeros.

Comment: Draw the function $f:x\mapsto \frac{x^4}{4}-\frac74x^3+\frac{13}{4}x^2+1$ on your favorite grapher.

Comment: @MarkBennet : that's what I've been trying for the last ten minutes. MuPAD/Geogebra/pencil... :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I think the comments from @MarkBennet and Nicolas FRANCOIS were the most useful for solving this.  Drawing the graph shows the solution nicely.

Comment: This looks like a problem you have collected from / inspired by some source. According to recent discussions in Meta, we are looking forward to including sources for all applicable questions. Can you provide the source by editing the question?Refer-https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken